# How do random variables form vector spaces with a defined inner product?

Tags: probability-distributions, vector-spaces, soft-question, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

I am well over my head on this topic, but I'm asking for a couple of conceptual, framing statements to understand the broader picture at an intuitive level.

In *Hilbert Space Methods in Probability and Statistical Inference* by Christopher G. Small, Don L. McLeish it can be read:

> Let $\mathbf G$ be the set of all functions ${\bf x}: \Omega \to
> > \mathbb R$ such that $({\mathbf x \land n{\bf 1}})\lor(-n{\bf1})\in
> > {\mathbf H}$ for all natural numbers $n$. The set $\mathbf G$ can be
>   shown to be a **vector space under the usual pointwise addition and
>   scalar multiplication**.

So what is the connection between the random variables (and specifically their probability density functions) and vector or inner product spaces. Specifically, and if these statements / questions are remotely close to reality, in what way are pdf's linear with scalar multiplication?

---

In answer to the comment, this is the passage quoted:

[image]

---

And this is the [link](http://www.randomservices.org/random/expect/Spaces.html) provided by @symplectomorphic, which really resolves the question:

> Many of the concepts in this chapter have elegant interpretations if
>   we think of real-valued random variables as vectors in a vector space.
>   In particular, variance and higher moments are related to the concept
>   of norm and distance, while covariance is related to inner product.
>   These connections can help unify and illuminate some of the ideas in
>   the chapter from a different point of view. Of course, real-valued
>   random variables are simply measurable, real-valued functions defined
>   on the sample space, so much of the discussion in this section is a
>   special case of our discussion of function spaces in the chapter on
>   Distributions, but recast in the notation of probability.
>
> As usual, our starting point is a random experiment modeled by a
>   probability space (Ω,F,P). Thus, Ω is the sample space, F is the
>   σ-algebra of events, and P is the probability measure. Our basic
>   vector space V consists of all real-valued random variables defined on
>   (Ω, F, P). Recall that random variables X1 and X2 are equivalent if
>   P(X1 = X2) = 1, in which case we write X1 ≡ X2. We consider two such
>   random variables as the same vector, so that technically, our vector
>   space consists of equivalence classes under this equivalence relation.
>   The addition operator corresponds to the usual addition of two
>   real-valued random variables, and the operation of scalar
>   multiplication corresponds to the usual multiplication of a
>   real-valued random variable by a real (non-random) number. These
>   operations are compatible with the equivalence relation in the sense
>   that if X1 ≡ X2 and Y1≡Y2 then X1 + Y1 ≡ X2 + Y2 and cX1 ≡ cX2 for c ∈ R. In
>   short, the vector space V is well-defined.

Comment: I suspect that $\land$ and $\lor$ are the minimum and the maximum, but what are $n\mathbf1$, $>\Bbb R$ and $>\mathbf H$?

Comment: @AlexM. Same question, though I suppose $\mathbf 1$ is just a vector of $1$'s.

Comment: Guys, not sure about this, but it may be an indicator variable, the way it is bolded (?).

Comment: Also, if you think of random variables as elements of $L^2$, they are in fact elements of a Hilbert space. This also gives conditional probability a neat geometric interpretation.

Comment: @AntoniParellada an indicator for what set/event, though?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist I understand that this may be more key than I realize, but if at all possible, I'd like to focus on the most general framework regarding the connection between random variables (and pdf's) and vector spaces. For instance, what is $L^2$? That is my level of (not) understanding at this point.

Comment: Your title question is making a semantics error, confusing the object of a structure with the structure itself. A random variable is a not a vector space. However, the collection of random variables satisfying certain properties is a vector space.

Comment: Also, what is a "continuous" random variable?

Comment: And what is a "probability Hilbert space"?

Comment: @AlexM. I'm probably misunderstanding you, but I think the term 'continuous random variable' is standard.

Comment: @symplectomorphic This is the type of comment I'm after. Especially as it connect to pdf's.

Comment: My comment is not an answer: it is a request that you make the title not prima facie absurd. What you mean to ask is whether, or how, random variables *form* a vector space, not whether random variables *are* vector spaces.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Fair enough, although I think I have expressed very clearly that I am not comfortable with the topic, and that I want just a layout of the main, framework concepts - a sketch. In this regard, correcting a misunderstanding in the title would be well within what could be expected from a didactic answer.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Now since I see downvotes, and petitions for closure. I will happily delete the question, apologizing for having offended in any way asking such self-evident silly question.

Comment: I didn't downvote. There is a good question here, but I think it's already been asked before (search for Hilbert space of random variables). All I'm saying is that your title makes no sense and betrays a lack of familiarity with the basic objects you're asking about.

Comment: [Here](http://www.randomservices.org/random/expect/Spaces.html) is a more elementary overview of the basic framework. You seem to be confusing random variables with their densities. The vector space being studied in the book you cite is the space of random variables, aka the space of measurable functions (satisfying certain conditions), not the space of density functions for those random variables. You're right that densities aren't closed under pointwise addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Thanks, I think this clarifies a bit the overall picture. If you have any inclination, your comments would make for a great answer, and I would accept it.

Comment: @AntoniParellada: I have a hard time understanding how the paragraph that you have inserted in your post answers your question while my answer doesn't, given that both say essentially the same thing. Also, notice that your random variables are Hilbert-space-valued, as opposed to real-valued. Also notice that the big quotation works with classes of random variables (on which you may **not** perform $\land$ and $\lor$) with equality up to null sets, while you work with "true" random variables. If it seems to you that that paragraph answers your question, then you haven't understood it! :)

Comment: @Alex M.: the random variables in the set $G$ *are* real-valued; they're functions with domain $\Omega$ and codomain $\mathbb{R}$. Anyway, I think the OP's real issue is in the final question, "in what way are pdf's linear with scalar multiplication?" The answer is that the vector space consists of random variables, not of their pdfs.

Comment: Thanks, @symplectomorphic I think the confusion is the fact that at a beginner's level vectors are either arrow, or polynomials, or Fourier functions. But a random variable is more abstract: a map from the sample space to the real line (typically). So it could (?) be understandable to miss the "equation" (the polynomial, or the Fourier series), and go looking for it in the pdf. This is as much as I can approximate it. Your linked helped a lot in seeing a rough sketch - a fuzzy NASA picture of some remote planets... For now.

Comment: Glad I can help. It seems you just aren't accustomed to thinking about *function spaces*, which are vector spaces of functions. You're right that the most elementary examples of vector spaces are more down to earth: sets of arrows or ordered $n$-tuples. But real-valued functions on some set also form a vector space under pointwise addition and pointwise scalar multiplication: adding two functions ("vectors") $f$ and $g$ gives a new function ("vector") $f+g$ whose value at $x$ is just $f(x)+g(x)$, etc. In your question the functions are the real-valued measurable functions on the sample space.

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaking "pointwise scalar multiplication" for "scalar product". For $\alpha \in \Bbb R$ and $\mathbf x \in \mathbf G$ one may define the *poinwise scalar multiplication* by $(\alpha \mathbf x) (\omega) = \alpha \big( \mathbf x (\omega) \big)$, for $\omega \in \Omega$. There is no mention of *scalar product* here.

Of course, if you really wanted, you could also define a scalar product by $\langle \mathbf x, \mathbf y \rangle = \int _\Omega \mathbf x (\omega) \mathbf y (\omega) \ \Bbb d \mu$ where $\mu$ is the measure on $\Omega$, but care must be taken in order to assure the convergence of the above integral for all $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$, and in order to make this scalar product non-degenerate (you'll have to work with classes of functions etc.). This could be done, for instance, by requiring $\mu$ to be finite. In any case, this is not what your text tries to convey.

Comment: Doesn't the fact that we're working in a probability space guarantee that $\mu$ is finite?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist: It does, but is it given that $\Omega$ is a probability space and not just a space with measure?

Comment: @AlexM. I suspect it is, but I suppose it is not exactly explicitly spelled out. Fair enough.